# Map columns in dataframe from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe.

```
is_active Device
True       1
False      2
```

I have a file called mapping.json

```
[
  {
    "description": "Desktop",
    "deviceId": "1"
  },
  {
    "description": "Smartphone",
    "deviceId": "2"
  },
  {
    "description": "Tablet",
    "deviceId": "3"
  }
]
```

I need to map Device with device id from mapping.json to get final result as:

```
is_active Device
True       Desktop
False      Smartphone
```

How can I achieve it using pandas.
I am doing:

```
with open('mapping.json', 'r') as file:
     c_map = json.load(file)
     output_df['Device'] = output_df['Device'].map(c_map)
```

It gives me error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rework `cmap` to be a dictionary:

```
cmap = {d['deviceId']: d['description'] for d in cmap}
```

Then `map` will work as expected.